# Return devise confirmation token in device 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

Now that Devise has removed the :confirmation_token from the database, how can I return the devise confirmation token in rspec?

I am trying to test the confirmable module by manually visiting the user_confirmation path with the confirmation token. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confirmation flow has changed. Now, the confirmation flow uses User.confirm_by_token. You can do something like this:

```
old_token = User.last.confirmation_token
new_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :confirmation_token, old_token)
User.last.update_attribute(:confirmation_token, new_token)
visit user_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: old_token)
```

Answer (score 10):

A slight variation on the very helpful answer by Leonardo Pinto:

```
# Generate new raw/encrypted confirmation token pair and update database.
# This lets us visit the new "raw" path to confirm the user.
raw_confirmation_token, db_confirmation_token = 
  Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :confirmation_token)
User.last.update_attribute(:confirmation_token, db_confirmation_token)
visit user_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: raw_confirmation_token)
```

Background:  As outlined in [this Platformatec blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/) under "Store digested tokens in the database," Devise 3.1+ sends the user a "raw" confirmation token, and saves an encrypted version in the database. When the user clicks on the raw link, the raw token is re-encrypted before searching in the database.  See `send_confirmation_instructions` and `generate_confirmation_token` in this source code:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb

This code generates a new pair of raw and encrypted tokens, updates the last User in the database with the new encrypted version, then `visit`s the raw version.  The token should match and the account should be confirmed.

Although not in the original question, I also wanted to test for the correct link in the Devise confirmation mailer, but I don't think that's possible:  when I create a user, the confirmation email is sent immediately, so the email's body contains the original raw token, not the new one generated here.